# Importing date field from superoffice caesar crm

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to import data from a superoffice caesar crm SQL database.
In this database there is a column called `CreateDATE` which is a float.

What is the proper way to convert this to `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` format?

The column
[image]

I tried something like this but it's not matching the date seen in the program so I'm guessing there something more to this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
Select
  dateadd(d,UpdateDATE,'1899-12-30')
from Activity where CustomerID = xxx order by UpdateDATE desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CAST` or `CONVERT` as the below:

```
DECLARE @DateVal DATETIME = '2016-08-12 13:57:15.347'
SELECT CAST(@DateVal AS FLOAT) -- 42592,5814276235

DECLARE @FloatVal FLOAT = 42592.5814276235
SELECT CAST(@FloatVal AS DATETIME) -- 2016-08-12 13:57:15.347
```